# Question about "interior" when talking about house in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

> Other room
>
> - laundry: community
> - rooms: living room
>
> **Interior** features
>
> - 2 story
> - security features: gated community

Interior? Is it refering to inside of the building ( complex) and separate stories in a complex? Or is it about two floors inside one house you live in?

Comment: Neither of those would be interior features. I'd guess you got that from a website with real estate listings? Those sites are all about marketing: some sales agent but those in that category for some other reason. Perhaps the was no applicable category for them, or the applicable category had many items already listed, and the writer wanted them to be more noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

"Interior," particularly in this context, is just related to anything *in* the house or building. For example, "interior design" is the choice of furniture and paint used in a house.

Someone might disagree with me, but I tend to think of "interior" as being a relatively temporary thing. That is, I don't view the layout of a house to be its "interior," although strictly speaking I suppose it could be. But again, I tend to relate it with things like furniture, artwork, paint, wallpaper, etc.

Where did you get the part you quoted from? If you wrote that yourself, I would pick a different word than "interior" to refer to the number of stories and the fact that it's a gated community. If it was from an English-speaking real estate company, I would be surprised upon reading it. That's definitely not what interior means, no matter how loosely you take it. You *could* get away with calling "other room" (which should be plural by the way--"rooms"), "interior features." But again, I tend to associate it connotatively with more temporary aspects of the home.

Comment: Not just anything in the house, but rather, everything in the house.